# SQL-query to find articles with at least one of the listed tags

Tags: sql, select, mysql

I have 3 tables: articles, tags and article_tag (the one which connects them).

I'd like to find all articles that have some (or all) of the tags listed in the query and order them by the number of matched tags. Is it possible?

Example in english:

```
Query: Find me all articles that have at least one of these tags "jazz, bass guitar, soul, funk", order them by the number of matched tags.

Output:
Article 1 (jazz, bass-guitar, soul, funk)
Article 2 (jazz, bass-guitar, soul)
Article 3 (jazz, bass-guitar)
Article 4 (funk)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
select articles.article_id, count(tags.tag_id) as num_tags, group_concat(distinct tag_name separator ',') as tags
from articles, article_tag, tags
where articles.tag_id = article_tag.tag_id
  and article_tag.tag_id = tags.tag_id
  and tags.tag_name in ( 'jazz', 'funk', 'soul', 'Britney Spears' )
group by articles.article_id
order by count(tags.tag_id) desc
```

Comment: +1 for GROUP_CONCAT(). But really, DISTINCT should not be necessary there - the schema should already enforce unique article/tag combinations. What I would add though is an ORDER BY tag_name so the list is neatly sorted alfabetically.

Comment: Yeah, schema wasn't posted so I wasn't sure what it would enforce.

Comment: Thanks. You made a small mistake though, articles.tag_id should probably be articles.article_id in the WHERE clause. But thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah you're right, that should be `articles.article_id = article_tag.article_id`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.* from articles a,
 (select article_id, count(*) cnt from article_tag at, tag t
  where t.name in ('jazz', 'bass-guitar', 'soul', 'funk')
  and at.tag_id = t.tag_id
  group by article_id) art_tag
where a.article_id = art_tag.article_id
order by art_tag.cnt desc
```

Comment: Won't order by the number of matched tags.